# Joi error: ValidationError: "value" must be of type object

Tags: javascript, joi

I was wondering why JOI is returning both an error and a value:

```
app.post("/api/courses", (req, res) => {
  const { error, value } = validateStuff(req.body.name);
  console.log(`error: ${error}
  value: ${value}`);

validateStuff = (course) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
  });
  return schema.validate(course);
};
```

```
postman POST request
{
    "name":"al"
}
```

output:

error: ValidationError: "value" must be of type object

value: al  (my post input)

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this issue, but for a different reason than the other answer above. My error message:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Error validating request payload","propertyErrors":{"value":"\"value\" must be of type object"}}
```

The issue was that I wasn't specifying a `Content-Type` header, and `node-fetch` was [inferring](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/4ae35388b078bddda238277142bf091898ce6fda/src/body.js#L302) the type to be `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`, which resulted in this error with `joi`.

Once I set the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `req.body` to validateStuff, if you want no error.

Your code passes the string from the `name` property right away

Or you could change your Joi schema to `const Joi.string().min(3).required()`

Your question states you wonder why schema.validate returns both an error and a value.

When destructuring like you did `const { error, value} = schema.validate()` you can do the following, because you could have an error at runtime or none.

```js
if (error) {
  // handle error
  // passed value might be needed
} else {
  // validation successful
}
```